# Why $.extend keep the function scope of the old object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a deep copy of an object with [`$.extend`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/).

The odd behaviour appear when I call the function `display` after making the deep copy in a new object `{}`.

This is happening because the function is using the *closure* of the `object` returned by `something()`. You can see this behaviour in the below image.

[image]

The result of the code below is `Name[undefined]`. The **expected** result is `Name[1]`.

```js
function something() {
    var self = {};
    self.name = "Name";
    self.display = function() {
        return self.name + "[" + self.index +"]";   
    }
    return self;
}
var obj = $.extend(true, {}, something(), { index : 1 });
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.display());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I know that removing the `{}` from parameters will solve my problem.

```
var obj = $.extend(true, something(), { index : 1 });
```

Or extracting the `object` in a new variable and adding the property after extending.

```
var smth = something();
var obj = $.extend(true, {}, smth, { index : 1 });
smth.index = 2;
```

What causes this behaviour? There are other ways to solve it?

Comment: I'm unsure what your *problem* is? I *thought* your *problem* was that `self.display()` referenced the object `self`, rather than the object `obj`, but neither removing `{}` from the parameters, or extracting `object` into a new variable will fix that, like you suggest it will.

Comment: @Matt The *solutions* I presented solve the problem, but I can't use them in production. The object returned by `something()`, in production, it's just *only one* and I have to make a copy.

Comment: Oh in fact... I see now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend only effects property references. It cannot enter functions and magically change their references.

The function `display` is scoped to the function `something`. As a result the object it references is self, and not `obj` or *any* of the new properties. A fun example is this:

```
var obj = $.extend(true, {}, something(), { name : "World" });
console.log(obj.display()); // Name[undefined]
```

Perhaps this would be just as surprising to you. In your use, extend is taking a blank object, and it is then using the object returned from `something()` to recursively collect every property in order to copy its value.

So `obj` ends up with the value of `name`, the value of `display`, and the value of `index` from the third argument's object.

The core issue here is the value of display. Display's value is a function. That function has an **[Execution Context<sup>ECMA</sup>](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3)**. Among other things, inside of this execution context are two environments for variables. A lexical environment, and a variable environment. The lexical environment is going to hold a set of variables from the parent scope of the context, and the variable environment is going to hold a set of variables from the executing scope.

The parent scope of the function for display is `something` so the lexical environment for `display` contains a reference to `self`. This reference will not be changed by extend because the value of display is still the function whose execution context is scoped to that specific `self` object.

In order to avoid using the reference to `self` which is stored in the execution context's lexical environment for `display`, you could use `this`. The execution context will also contain a reference to `this`. However, the binding for `this` *can* change, and will change during `extend`. So changing your code to use `this` as opposed to self inside of `display`

```
function something() {
    var self = {};
    self.name = "Name";
    self.display = function() {
        return this.name + "[" + this.index +"]";
    }
    return self;
}
```

will properly show any new values because it's this binding will change during extend and that will mean the new `this`'s execution context is used, and by relation its variable and lexical environments will also be used.

```
console.log(obj.display()); //Name[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn `something()` to a constructor function. You would have to instantiate it but you would get a new instance each time with it's own scope:

```
function something() {
    this.name = "Name";
    this.display = function() {
        return this.name + "[" + this.index +"]";   
    }
}
var obj = $.extend(true, {}, new something(), { index : 1 });
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.display());
```